# What happens when using python input() if no TTY?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, telethon

I am trying to write an API client for Telegram using Telethon.

https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon

If you create a `TelegramClient(session)` it prompts for input upon initialization if your session isn’t authorized.

This is great when manually running the program from the terminal, but what if I want to run it inside a daemon or cron job?

They are using the default Input method from python3 to gather the input. I don’t see any way in the library to specify a session file and check if it’s logged in that can be run before initializing a `TelegramClient`, and it’s the initializer that will prompt for input if not logged in.

This feels like a catch 22! Does anybody know if this might produce an error that could be caught? Or what happens when `input()` is run with no tty?  Would it just hang? Could I add a timeout in that case?

Thanks in advance for helping me understand better!

Comment: You can use input piping with `<` in bash. `python script.py < "John"`

Comment: Input piping doesn’t help. I need to enter a 2FA code if prompted. Bogus input might cause a crash that I can leverage, but that feels like a hack.

Comment: Well if you really want to check if session is valid, you can use `TelegramClient.get_messages()` method. It raises exception if session isnt valid and you can use `StringSession` class to define new `Session` .

Answer (score 0):

You are affirming that the initialization of `TelegramClient` invokes the `input` function as default, but this is done inside the `TelegramClient.start` method ([docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.auth.AuthMethods.start)).

Taking the solution that you give at the end of your question is a fair aproach, so let's use a timeout when invoking `input`.

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, wait_for, TimeoutError
from functools import partial
from telethon import TelegramClient

async def ainput(prompt):
    """Reads input from stdin in an async way"""
    loop = get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, print, prompt)
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, input)

async def get_code(timeout):
    """Waits for the code from stdin with a timeout"""
    try:
        return await wait_for(
            ainput("Please, type the code you received: "),
            timeout=timeout
        )
    except TimeoutError:
        pass

client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash).start(
    phone=phone,
    code_callback=partial(get_code, 30)
)
```

You should keep in mind that when you call `start` the arguments `phone`, and `password` also reads from stdin if it isn't provided a callable or default value, so you can handle them like in this example with `code_callback`.

In your case you can get the code from a POST to your API or in other way, just get creative and write the callable that fits your needs.